# using useState to prevent both redeclares and re-runs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm cleaning up the warnings in the console before I proceed any and I have a bunch of components that are slopped together (structured) very similarly. The values are specific to each component. It appears that trying to set State within an if statement isn't a brilliant idea.

Original solution with redeclares:

```js
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState({
    quoteId: false,
    quotePage: false,
    quoteExcerpt: false,
    quoteComment: false,
  });

  var allEmpty = true;

  if (
    value.quoteId &&
    value.quotePage &&
    value.quoteExcerpt &&
    value.quoteComment === false
  ) {
    var quoteSect = false;
    var allEmpty = true;
  }
  if (
    value.quoteId ||
    value.quotePage ||
    value.quoteExcerpt ||
    value.quoteComment === true
  ) {
    var allEmpty = false;
    var quoteSect = true;
  }
```

Close, but broken solution due to  `Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.`:

```js
  const [empty, setEmpty] = React.useState(true)

  const [value, setValue] = React.useState({
    quoteId: false,
    quotePage: false,
    quoteExcerpt: false,
    quoteComment: false,
  });

  if (
    value.quoteId &&
    value.quotePage &&
    value.quoteExcerpt &&
    value.quoteComment === false
  ) {
    var quoteSect = false;
    setEmpty(true);
  }
  if (
    value.quoteId ||
    value.quotePage ||
    value.quoteExcerpt ||
    value.quoteComment === true
  ) {
    setEmpty(false);
    var quoteSect = true;
  }
```

Comment: var uses global scope, so you should probably avoid that. context API would be a better way to handle something you need to share with multiple components. if contextApi doesnt solve that problem... you should probably give us more code to see, or a codepen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `empty` "state" seems *entirely* derived from the `value` state, which means it probably doesn't belong in state. The render looping is caused by continually setting state in the component body as an unintentional side-effect.

I think `empty` can just be a local variable set each render cycle, derived from the current `value` state value.

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState({
  quoteId: false,
  quotePage: false,
  quoteExcerpt: false,
  quoteComment: false,
});

const empty = (
  value.quoteId &&
  value.quotePage &&
  value.quoteExcerpt &&
  !value.quoteComment
) || (
  value.quoteId ||
  value.quotePage ||
  value.quoteExcerpt ||
  value.quoteComment
);
```

If you need a more stable `empty` reference then use the `useMemo` hook.

```
const empty = useMemo(() => {
  return (
    value.quoteId &&
    value.quotePage &&
    value.quoteExcerpt &&
    !value.quoteComment
  ) || (
    value.quoteId ||
    value.quotePage ||
    value.quoteExcerpt ||
    value.quoteComment
  );
}, [value]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello first you need to note Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop  means that the component will always recheck if the state changed since you added the logic directly in the component . use functions like so

```
      const checkEmpty =((Props)) => {

                      if(props ..){

              setState(prevState = !prevState)  ; 

              }
```

call the function inside a useEffect(()=> checkEmpty(StateHere)  , []) if your desire is to check the data onComponentDidmount  the [] to avoid endless loop .  ok now the best practice is to add that state in a reducer and use redux hook useSelector to grab your state from there and run checks as above . mainly if your working with backend or the state that you defined comes from another container to avoid useState you can replace it with redux and it's actions ext ...

Comment: thank you for sharing another possible method :)